# How Lots of ComputeBuffers at Once Affect Performance Unity

Tags: unity, c#, performance, gpu, compute-shader

How will lots `ComputeBuffer` instances affect performance? And why?
I know that I should call `ComputeBuffer.Release()` on every `ComputeBuffer` I create, but will it affect performance if I were to have lots of open `ComputeBuffers` at once? and by "lots" I mean hundreds to thousands.
It of course goes without saying that all of those `ComputeBuffers` will be released at some point, possibly at the same time.

Comment: What does your profiling tell you when you make a synthetic test with many compute buffers on your target hardware? You can trust that empirical evidence far more than the hearsay of strangers on the Internet, whose experience may not be reflective of your situation or hardware targets.

Comment: @DMGregory I asked the question in case anyone already knows and could possibly also explain to me why it does / doesn't affects performance, I know I could test it by myself but I wouldn't get the "why", just the "is".

Comment: @DMGregory Since I can see it wasn't clear, I fixed it and edited the question.

Comment: "will it affect performance" yes. How strongly? It depends.